# gio mount says "volume doesn't implement mount" when run as non-root

Tags: linux, debian, samba, mount

All involved OSes are Debian 10

I run a decent size network for a scientific insitute.
Users have separate PCs to work on. Login is handled locally.
To connect users and data, we run a samba server ("cloud" -- just to share data, separate login details) and a login server ("node") that's accessible worldwide
Users can successfully use the "archive" share on "cloud" via Nautilus or Dolphin.
However I want to enable them to also mount / access the cloud on the "node"

I have installed `gvfs-backends` and `gvfs-fuse` and added all users to the `fuse` group.

Using `gio mount smb://cloud.[fqdn]/archive` root can mount the share using any samba-username + password and access it in `/run/user/0/gvfs/`

Doing the same with any non-root user yields `volume doesn't implement mount`.

I have no idea how to interpret that since the volume is obviously mountable.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue when getting a Debian 10 system up and running with the command line only at first with no desktop environment yet installed.

After installing the packages:

```
sudo apt install gvfs-fuse gvfs-backends libglib2.0-bin
```

I attempted an SMB mount with `gio` while logged in as my regular user (the one created by the Debian installation with uid `1000`), but I got the same `volume doesn't implement mount` error.

I noted that the depended-upon `gvfs-daemons` package containing `gvfsd` had a configuration for a service that runs as a regular user in its package:

```
$ dpkg -L gvfs-daemons
...
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gvfs-daemon.service
...
```

To manually launch that in an already logged-in regular user session, I did:

```
systemctl --user start gvfs-daemon
```

After that the `gio mount` worked without issue and I was able to access the mounted volumes under `/run/user/1000/gvfs/`.

I haven't had to do this manually in later sessions -- it may only be necessary in a login session that was already running before the package was installed.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer for another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523563), the issue might be the lack of a dbus session. See:

```
laptop $ ssh pi
pi $ gio mount smb://192.168.86.18/Video
gio: smb://192.168.86.18/Video: volume doesn’t implement mount
```

After connecting to my headless Raspberry Pi over ssh, I can't mount things using gio/gvfs. Then, I can start a dbus session and run a new shell inside it:

```
pi $ dbus-run-session bash

pi $ gio mount smb://192.168.12.34/Foobar
…
Password required for share foobar on 192.168.12.34
…

pi $ mount | tail
…
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1002/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1002,group_id=1002)

pi $
```

As soon as that dbus session ends, the mount gets umounted.

Comment: I just plain didn't realize that `gio mount` could not be used in a regular ssh session for a user that already has a dbus session due to being logged in locally -- it has to be done in the local login session (or presumably with whatever environment vars that are needed to find the dbus session set)